# Robot Framework - Selenium Library Import Issue on Ride (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, automation, anaconda, robotframework, rpa

I had some troubles to install selenium library at first, after I went trough some websites, I installed the library using the command `pip install -U selenium` on prompt command, however, after importing the library to Ride, the name appears in red as photos below shows
[image][image]

I looked into Lib (Ananconda3) folder to check if there was any folder related to Selenium and I found it out there, therefore, I dont understand why Ride is not importing it properly
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciate (ps. I dont know if it is relevant, but I'm using Windows 10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium doesn't equal SeleniumLibrary.

You need to follow [instalation instructions](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary).

If you want to use selenium in RF, you need to install:

- selenium => you have done it
- SeleniumLibrary => you haven't done it, follow the instructions I linked, `$ pip install -U robotframework-seleniumlibrary`
- RF => it seems (from the screen) you have done it, `$ pip install -U robotframework`

After these steps, you can import SeleniumLibrary in RF:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
```

and you should see no errors.